# without indicate field name in PHP using MySQL get all data

Tags: php, mysql

Without indicate field name in PHP using MySQL get data.

```
while ($row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_data)) {
    $html .='<td>'.$row_data['without_fieldname'].'</td>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`mysql_fetch_row`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_row), then you can use `$row_data[0]` etc.

```
while ($row_data = mysql_fetch_row($res_data)) {
    $html .= '<tr>';
    for($i = 0; $i < count($row_data); $i++) {
        $html .='<td>'.$row_data[$i].'</td>';
    }
    $html .= '</tr>';
}
```

Please note that you should not combine this with `SELECT *` as any changes to the column order would break your code.

Comment: this is fetch the first row of data but i will get all data from database

Comment: Well you still need the `while` loop..

Comment: $count = 1;
   $html .="<tr class='ui-widget-content'>";
   while ($row_data = mysql_fetch_row($res_data)) {
    $html .='<td>'.$row_data[$count].'</td>';
    $count ++;
   }
   $html .="</tr>";

Comment: Ah, you want to iterate over the columns.

Comment: how can i generate html format to ms access file can u give any idea?

Comment: That is completely unrelated to this question. Please create a new question for this.

Comment: thanks a lot for previous answers

Comment: A better way to say thanks is accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark icon on the left side of the answer.